# Windows command line FIND command is very slow

Tags: windows, command-line

i am using FIND on the command line to reduce a very large csv file to a smaller file containing only lines that have a certain string in them.

Original file is 339MB with millions of lines.  output file is 20MB with about 550K lines. Takes a very log time - more than 1 hour - to run.

How can I make my find command more efficient and faster to complete?

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free

Product ID:                00329-00000-00003-AA571
Original Install Date:     7/21/2020, 8:23:02 AM
System Boot Time:          11/20/2020, 7:13:17 PM
System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
System Model:              VMware Virtual Platform
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              2 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 0 GenuineIntel ~2594 Mhz
                           [02]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 0 GenuineIntel ~2594 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Phoenix Technologies LTD 6.00, 12/12/2018
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     16,384 MB
Available Physical Memory: 7,412 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  18,816 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 10,085 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    8,731 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

*Find* is an ancient utility, dating from the early days of Windows, so it's not
surprising that it's not very fast.

You can't change the way that *Find* works, so the only solution is to use
another third-party search product.

You may look for a product coming from the Linux Grep family, such as
[grepWin](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html)
or any of its free
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/grepwin/?license=free).
Try them until you find one that fits your needs, perhaps one that has a GUI
interface and doesn't only work in the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You could try PowerShell instead. I don't know if it's faster, but it's worth a try.

```sh
Select-String -Path "Filename.txt" -Pattern "WhatToLookFor" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line | Out-File "results.txt"
```

`Select-String` searches for text

`Select-Object` selects the `Line` property of the results from Select-String

`Out-File` writes the output to a file

Comment: gotta learn power shell.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions.

I should have seen this sooner.  I was running the command on data stored on a network drive.  when i moved the input file to a local disk, and made sure the output was also going to a local file, performance improved to acceptable levels.  Actually pretty fast now, finishing in about 1 minute.

Not feeing real smart right now.

again, thank you